# Is that possible to use switch statement inside a constructor in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constructor

I am developing a website using reactjs and node. My problem is that I am not sure whether I have used the best practice to get the expected result. In following code I wanted to set the initial state of the class conditionally. For that I used switch statement inside the class constructor. My question is, is there any solution better than this and is this the best practice to get what I need.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
constructor(props: FeedbackFormProps) {
   super(props);
   const {
     review: { courseReview, studentReview }
   } = props;

   switch (props.isCourseReview) {
      case true:
         this.state = {
            values: {
                ranking: courseReview.length > 0 ? courseReview[0].rate : 
                0,
                comment: courseReview.length > 0 ? 
                courseReview[0].reviewText : ""
           },
           errors: {
             comment: null
           },
           isFeedbackEdit: courseReview.length > 0 ? true : false
       };
       break;
    case false:
       this.state = {
          values: {
              ranking: studentReview.length > 0 ? studentReview[0].rating 
              : 0,
              comment: studentReview.length > 0 ? 
              studentReview[0].comment_en : ""
         },
         errors: {
           comment: null
         },
         isFeedbackEdit: studentReview.length > 0 ? true : false
      };
      break;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Create one function and keep all these code in that then call that function in constructor then it's look good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good option if the initialization is going to depend on a prop coming from the parent component.

If you want to make it cleaner you could create a function in a ".business" file where passing a parameter would return the state as you want and here just set the state with that function passing the parameter.

This would make the component cleaner and you could isolate that logic to be tested and be correct.

**I would do it that way, we could refactor even more:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-9dpxft?file=sample.tsx

Answer (score 0):

You can change code with this simple way:

```
constructor(props: FeedbackFormProps) {
   super(props);
   const {
     review: { courseReview, studentReview }
   } = props;
   const reviews = studentReview 
   if (props.isCourseReview) reviews = courseReview
   const countReviews = reviews.length
   this.state = {
      values: {
          ranking: countReviews ? reviews[0].rating : 0,
          comment: countReviews ? reviews[0].comment_en : ""
     },
     errors: {
       comment: null
     },
     isFeedbackEdit: countReviews  ? true : false
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Constructor must to be as clean as possible. Try this:

```
class YourClass extends Component {
    constructor(props: FeedbackFormProps) {
        super(props);

        this.state = this.initState(props);
    }

    initState(props) {
        const {
            review: { courseReview, studentReview }
        } = props;

        let result;

        switch (props.isCourseReview) {
            case true:
                result = {
                    values: {
                        ranking: courseReview.length > 0 ? courseReview[0].rate :
                            0,
                        comment: courseReview.length > 0 ?
                            courseReview[0].reviewText : ""
                    },
                    errors: {
                        comment: null
                    },
                    isFeedbackEdit: courseReview.length > 0 ? true : false
                };
                break;
            case false:
                result = {
                    values: {
                        ranking: studentReview.length > 0 ? studentReview[0].rating
                            : 0,
                        comment: studentReview.length > 0 ?
                            studentReview[0].comment_en : ""
                    },
                    errors: {
                        comment: null
                    },
                    isFeedbackEdit: studentReview.length > 0 ? true : false
                };
                break;
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another way with conditions

```
const reviewType = props.isCourseReview ? 'courseReview' : 'studentReview';
const currentReview = props.review[reviewType];
// maybe it's good idea to name it isFeedbackEdit not curentReviewExist
const curentReviewExist = currentReview.length > 0;

this.state = {
   errors: {
     comment: null
   },
   values: {
     ranking: curentReviewExist ? currentReview[0].rate : 0,
     comment: curentReviewExist ? currentReview[0].reviewText : ""
   },
   // curentReviewExist - boolean value
   isFeedbackEdit: curentReviewExist
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing inherently wrong with using a `switch` in a constructor, but doing so when the cases are `true` and `false` ignores the power inherent in the word "if".

Assuming the distinction you made between "rate" and "rating" was a typo, you could reduce your code to:

```
constructor(props: FeedbackFormProps) {
  super(props);

  const review = props.isCourseReview ? props.review.courseReview[0] : props.review.studentReview[0];
  const isFeedbackEdit = !!review;
  const errors = { comment: null };
  const values = isFeedbackEdit ? {
    ranking: review.rate,
    comment: review.reviewText,
  } : {
    ranking: 0,
    comment: "",
  };
  this.state = { values, errors, isFeedbackEdit };
}
```